# Entity Framework Core dependency injection to models

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core / C#, and trying to learn. I have read tutorials, watched videos, and even bought a book. I wanted to inject my `AppDBcontext` to my models..

Here is my `Startup` class

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        string dbConnection = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:AzureSQL"];

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(dbConnection);
        });

        services.AddScoped<AppDbContext>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and my `AppDbContext.cs`

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Monthly> Monthly { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bill> Bill { get; set; }
}
```

I tried something like from my models

```
public class Bill
{
    public AppDbContext _ctx;
    public Bill(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _ctx = db;
    }

    public class BillGetParams
    {
        public string MonthlyID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string BillID { get; set; }
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? MonthlyID { get; set; }
    public string BillName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int? Amount { get; set; }
    public bool? Payed { get; set; }
    public bool? Recursive { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public static async Task<List<Bill>> LoadBills(BillGetParams billParams)
    {
        var bills = _ctx.Bill.FromSql($@"
        SELECT * FROM bills WHERE MonthlyId={billParams.MonthlyID}");

        return await bills.ToListAsync();
    }

    public static async Task<Bill> LoadBill(BillGetParams param)
    {
        var bill = _ctx.Bill.FromSql($@"
            SELECT * FROM bills
                WHERE UserID='{param.UserID}' AND ID='{param.BillID}'
        ");

        return await bill.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

edit: added partial code for `Bill` Class and to methods that use `_ctx`, also update the constructor by removing `static` and private->public;

I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

because it seemed like the assignment of `db` to `_ctx` never happened..

I'm not sure which is best, but I use my `AppDbContext` before like this. Should I continue using it like this?

```
using(var ctx = new AppDbContext())
{
    var bills = ctx.Bill.FromSql($@"select 1 from bills")
    // do stuff
}
```

From the internet examples, DI worked fine from controllers.. but I don't want to do SQL stuff from controllers.. is there a better way to abstract SQL / data access in `dotnet`? Or I am doing it wrong?

**solution1:** so after reading, tryouts, solutions from @Bharat, and experiments. I solved my problem, in simplest way.. hopefully I am right. I added this in my `BillController` that use `Bill.LoadBill()` I can access my sql well now.

```
    private Bill _bill;
    public BillController(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _bill = new Bill(db);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Change `private` access modifier on your constructor method to `public Bill (...)`, I would also question why you have it `static` in `private static AppDbContext _ctx;`?

Comment: thanks for the reply, why i have `private static AppDbContext` is because my editor `vs code` keep complaining to me `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Bill._ctx'`

Comment: Where you are registering `Bill` class ? as i don't see any where. Because this will give you a instance of `AppDbContext()`

Comment: @Bharat sorry I'm new to Dotnet, what do you mean by registering `Bill` class? I'm sure I've added it to `AppDbContext.cs`

Comment: Wherever  you are using `var bills = _ctx.Bill.FromSql($@"select 1");` you need to pass `AppDbContext()` as parameter to your bill class or if you are using Unity or ninject like lib then you need to register your `bill` class to resolve all dependencies  or you can show your code where you are using `var bills = _ctx.Bill.FromSql($@"select 1");` so we can know what is wrong.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the partial `Bill` class code. this may look noob and ugly, pardon me I am still 2 weeks old from C#/dotnet. and the `FromSql($@"select 1")` is just sample `SQL`, sorry for that.

Comment: you must calling `Bill.LoadBill()` methods from some where to get data from sql. so there you need to do like `Bill yourInstanceName = new Bill(new AppDbContext())` this will provide context to your `_ctx` using constructure.

Comment: @BharatPatidar that worked for me! i wrote a DI in a controller. I will update my post. thank you! this is the simplest solution. I will also re-architecture the data access to use a service. like the samples from Joel

Comment: You are most welcome!!

Answer (score 2):

The biggest mistake i see is this one:

```
public class Bill
{
    public AppDbContext _ctx;
    public Bill(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _ctx = db;
    }

    public static async Task<List<Bill>> LoadBills(BillGetParams billParams)
    {
         var bill = _ctx... //trying to acces an instance property in static context, does not work. and shouldn't even compile.
    }
}
```

### Plea to archictural change

I think the idea is nice to provide models with methods to access instances of them directly but please don't do this, even if it is to fill extra properties or lists.

This way you are splitting our DataAccess code (sql) throughout your application.
Instead its better to group all your dataAcces in controllers or even better in a sepearate project and as Services.

The advantages of a service is that:

- you can resolve it through the IOC container
- No problems of weird model constructors (now every model needs AppDbContext even if it doesnt need it)
- You can easily replace a service with another if it implements the same interface. (and you use this interface ofcourse)
- Static methods are not overrideable while virtual instance methods are. (this will lead to problems when your project grows bigger)

It would result in the following code:

```
public class EntityFrameworkBillService : IBillService
{
    public AppDbContext _ctx;
    public Bill(AppDbContext db)
    {
        _ctx = db;
    }

    public async Task<List<Bill>> GetBills(BillGetParams billParams)
    {
         var bill = _ctx... //trying to acces an instance property in static context, does not work. and shouldn't even compile.
    }
}
//startup.cs:
services.AddTransient<IBillService,EntityFrameworkBillService>()

//Usage 
public MyController(IBillService billService) //constructor
{
    var dollahBills = billService.GetBills();
}

 //And if you really wish this method to be there, and be lazy (but be warned: its an anti pattern)
public class Bill
{
    public static async Task<List<Bill>> GetBills(BillGetParams billParams)
    {
         //Make sure your ServiceProvider is available as static on Program in startup.cs.
         return Program.ServiceProvider.Resolve<IBillService>().GetBills(billParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the point, I'll take that as an advice. as a try experiment, this is what I can pull out. maybe give me a few more weeks, I will make it right :) and maybe create more test app and simple web api services for our production app..

Comment: I will try what I can do with that example, it look so clean. I'll do it now

Comment: @Hokutosei It might be a bit psuedo code since i didnt use an IDE so you might need to cleanup until you get it working, but this concept should always work. The downside is you will be needing +1 class per model, for the service and +1 if you want to abstract it: the interface. (So you will end up with more code)

Comment: thank you for the point, I'm not sure whether should I use this since I would require to create a new files.. but it is a good point I think to make it as a service

Answer (score 1):

### System.NullReferenceException

The reason why you are getting a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` is because your constructor method is `private`:

> ```
> private Bill(AppDbContext db)
> {
>     _ctx = db;
> }
> ```

**Solution:** Your constructor should be `public`.

Otherwise it is not accessible outside of it's own class. You can test this by placing a breakpoint on `_ctx = db` and you will see that it is not getting called.

To further your reading and understanding, I would recommend you read this Microsoft Documentation: [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: this seemed to be not working.. I still get `_ctx == null`